# How to get SqlAlchemy Table to read "implicit" schema

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Using table creation as normal:

```
t = Table(name, meta, [columns ...])
```

This is the first run where I create the table. In future executions I would like to use the table without having to indicate the [columns]. This seems redundant as it should already be specified in the table schema. In other words, for future accesses, I'd like to simply do:

```
t = Table(name, meta)  # columns already read from schema
```

Is there a way to do this in SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Reflecting Database Objects](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#reflecting-database-objects) of SA documentation:

```
t = Table(name, meta, autoload=True)#, autoload_with=engine)
```